# Slackware: wireless really slow

Tags: wifi

Problem: my wireless is run on 11Mb(sic!) 
I'm on slackware 14.1

iwconfig said

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"ops!"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.472 GHz  Access Point: ops!   
      Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:3  Invalid misc:52   Missed beacon:0
```

this is the rc.inet1.conf

```
#WLAN_ESSID[4]=BARRIER05
WLAN_MODE[4]="Ad-Hoc"
WLAN_RATE[4]="54M"
WLAN_CHANNEL[4]="auto"
WLAN_WPA[4]="wpa_supplicant"
WLAN_WPADRIVER[4]="nl80211"
```

I have set Ad-Hoc because i read somewhere 54M is possible only under "Ad-hoc"
mode.

This is lspci output for the card

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 020c
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at f7d80000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Of course router support over 54M(is 300M router)
No way to get 54M?
Thanks

Comment: The main problem I see with your current situation is that the wireless signal quality is very poor: "Link Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm". Until you can do something to improve that, there is probably not much you can do to improve the connection.

Comment: I try to put laptop near the router 3 meters distance and...nothing change